# Bayesian Model does not learn with tensorflow probability and keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, bayesian-networks, tensorflow-probability

I want to estimate epistemic uncertainty of my model. So I converted all layers into tensorflow probability layers. The model gives no errors back, but it also not learning anything. The model has two outputs and the losses of both outputs do not change at all. On the other hand, the overall loss of the model is shrinking, but seems not be related to the other losses at all, which I cant explain.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import tensorflow as tf
from plot.plot_utils import plot_model_metrics
from Custom_Keras_layers.ProbSqueezeExcite import squeeze_excite_block

inp = keras.layers.Input(shape=[self.timesteps, self.features])
    # left side
    # 1 Conv1D block
    l = tfp.layers.Convolution1DFlipout(filters=2*self.features, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)(inp)
    l = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(l)
    if squeeze_excite == 1:
        l = squeeze_excite_block(l)
    l = keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(l, training=True)

    # 1 Conv1D block
    l = tfp.layers.Convolution1DFlipout(filters=4 * self.features, kernel_size=4, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)(l)
    l = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(l)
    if squeeze_excite == 1:
        l = squeeze_excite_block(l)
    l = keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(l, training=True)

    # 1 lstm bock
    l = keras.layers.LSTM(32, recurrent_dropout=dropout_rate, dropout=dropout_rate)(l, training=True)

    # letf output layer
    l = tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(self.classes, activation=tf.nn.softmax, name='left')(l)

    # right side
    # 1 Conv1D block
    r = tfp.layers.Convolution1DFlipout(filters=2 * self.features, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)(inp)
    r = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(r)
    if squeeze_excite == 1:
        r = squeeze_excite_block(r)
    r = keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(r, training=True)

    # 1 Conv1D block
    r = tfp.layers.Convolution1DFlipout(filters=4 * self.features, kernel_size=4, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)(r)
    r = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(r)
    if squeeze_excite == 1:
        r = squeeze_excite_block(r)
    r = keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(r, training=True)

    # 1 lstm bock
    r = keras.layers.LSTM(32, recurrent_dropout=dropout_rate, dropout=dropout_rate)(r, training=True)

    # letf output layer
    r = tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(self.classes, activation=tf.nn.softmax, name='right')(r)

    model = keras.models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=[l, r])

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr)
    losses = {
        "left": self._neg_log_likelihood_bayesian,
        "right": self._neg_log_likelihood_bayesian}
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=losses, metrics=['accuracy'])
    self.model = model
```

and the loss function is defined as follows:

```
    def _neg_log_likelihood_bayesian(self, y_true, y_pred):
    labels_distribution = tfp.distributions.Categorical(logits=y_pred)
    neg_log_likelihood = -tf.reduce_mean(labels_distribution.log_prob(tf.argmax(y_true, axis=-1)))
    kl = sum(self.model.losses) / self.trainNUM
    loss = neg_log_likelihood + kl
    return loss
```

Any help would be appreciated. The overall loss starts at 45000, whereas the two outputs losses are at around 1,3. It is very strange to me.

Comment: Are you using `keras = tf.keras`?

Comment: yes, forgot to add my imports.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to this post on the issues forum of github tensorflow, I found out how to solve it https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/282
You have to scale the KL sum within each tfp layer:

```
 kernel_divergence_fn=lambda q, p, _: tfp.distributions.kl_divergence(q, p) / tf.to_float(train.num_examples))
```

Furthermore I changed the loss function to :

> neg_log_likelihood =
>   tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y_true,
>   logits=y_pred)

That did it for me, now my model is properly training.

Answer (score 0):

The overall loss might already include the prior loss kl(sampled weights||prior), so could be doubke counted? (I'm not sure how Keras handles this.) Another thought is to try using reduce_sum instead of reduce_mean.

Comment: I found this loss function on the tensorflow website. I states that the kl term is critical and should only be updated once per epoch. I am not quit sure how to accomplish this by now. 
neg_log_likelihood = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    labels=labels, logits=logits)

kl = sum(model.losses)

loss = neg_log_likelihood + kl